# Password generator with Secure Random

Tags: java, random

I have a small program in Java with GUI, which is generating passwords using **Secure Random**. I am posting my code here because I want to **correct myself** in style and, eventually, in efficiency of writing code.

Should I use try catch in, for example, button handling or password generating? I saw some user answers who discouraged using try catch statement. I am reading a lot, and I see that everyone has own opinion.

On Win7 & NetBeans IDE program look like this:

[image: password Generator]

I have 4 files:

**Main.java**

```
package passwordgenerator;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

public class Main {

    private static void loadGUI() {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
                GUI gui = new GUI();
                gui.createAndShowGUI();
                gui.setVisible(true);
            });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        loadGUI();
    }
}
```

**GUI.java** (my functions are on bottom of this file) **edited**

```
package passwordgenerator;

import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GUI extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private static final String UPPERCASE_CHARACTERS = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    private static final String LOWERCASE_CHARACTERS = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    private static final String NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = "1234567890";
    private static final String SPECIAL_CHARACTERS = "~!@#$%^&*()_|";

    /**
     *  Launches GUI.
     *  Creates and configures JFrame, adds panel (represented by this class).
     */
    public void createAndShowGUI() {
        initComponents();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("password generator @re");
        //frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(FRAME_MIN_WIDTH, FRAME_MIN_HEIGHT));
        frame.add(this);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        buttonGroup1 = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup();
        buttonGroup2 = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup();
        buttonGroup3 = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup();
        buttonGroup4 = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup();
        btnGenerate = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        passwordField = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        useAlphanumeric = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        useSpecialChars = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        useLowerAlphabet = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        jSlider1 = new javax.swing.JSlider();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        numberOfCharacters = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        btnGenerate.setMnemonic('\r');
        btnGenerate.setText("generate password");
        btnGenerate.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnGenerateActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton2.setText("copy to clipboard");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                copyToClipboard(evt);
            }
        });

        passwordField.setColumns(20);
        passwordField.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(passwordField);

        useAlphanumeric.setSelected(true);
        useAlphanumeric.setText("1-9");

        useSpecialChars.setSelected(true);
        useSpecialChars.setText("special chars (~!@#$...)");

        jLabel1.setText("mixing password chars ");

        useLowerAlphabet.setSelected(true);
        useLowerAlphabet.setText("a-z");

        jSlider1.setMajorTickSpacing(3);
        jSlider1.setMaximum(30);
        jSlider1.setMinimum(5);
        jSlider1.setMinorTickSpacing(1);
        jSlider1.setPaintLabels(true);
        jSlider1.setPaintTicks(true);
        jSlider1.setValue(8);
        jSlider1.addChangeListener(new javax.swing.event.ChangeListener() {
            public void stateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {
                sliderStateChanged(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel2.setText("number of characters:");

        numberOfCharacters.setText("8");

        jLabel4.setText("✓ A-Z");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(26, 26, 26)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 347, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(useSpecialChars)
                            .addComponent(useAlphanumeric))
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(62, 62, 62)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addComponent(useLowerAlphabet)
                                    .addComponent(numberOfCharacters, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 30, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 41, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addGap(117, 117, 117))))))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(56, 56, 56)
                        .addComponent(jButton2)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(btnGenerate, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 160, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(102, 102, 102)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2)))
                .addContainerGap(51, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(91, 91, 91)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(44, 44, 44)
                        .addComponent(jSlider1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 313, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(14, 14, 14)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(useAlphanumeric)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(useSpecialChars)
                    .addComponent(useLowerAlphabet))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 3, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(numberOfCharacters)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jSlider1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 32, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(btnGenerate, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 32, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(15, 15, 15))
        );
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void btnGenerateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        String charactersToBeUsed = "";

        charactersToBeUsed = UPPERCASE_CHARACTERS; // always

        if (useLowerAlphabet.isSelected()) {
            charactersToBeUsed += LOWERCASE_CHARACTERS;
        }
        if (useAlphanumeric.isSelected()) {
            charactersToBeUsed += NUMERIC_CHARACTERS;
        }
        if (useSpecialChars.isSelected()) {
            charactersToBeUsed += SPECIAL_CHARACTERS;
        }
        PasswordGenerator pg = new PasswordGenerator(charactersToBeUsed);
        int numberOfChars = Integer.parseInt(numberOfCharacters.getText());

        String pw = pg.generate(numberOfChars);

        passwordField.setEditable(false);
        passwordField.setText(pw);
    }                                           

    private void sliderStateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {                                    
        JSlider source = (JSlider) evt.getSource();
        if (!source.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
            numberOfCharacters.setText(Integer.toString(source.getValue()));
        }
    }                                   

    private void copyToClipboard(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                 
        String myString = passwordField.getText();
        StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection (myString);
        Clipboard clpbrd = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard ();
        clpbrd.setContents (stringSelection, null);
    }                                


    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton btnGenerate;
    private javax.swing.ButtonGroup buttonGroup1;
    private javax.swing.ButtonGroup buttonGroup2;
    private javax.swing.ButtonGroup buttonGroup3;
    private javax.swing.ButtonGroup buttonGroup4;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private static javax.swing.JSlider jSlider1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel numberOfCharacters;
    public static javax.swing.JTextArea passwordField;
    public static javax.swing.JCheckBox useAlphanumeric;
    public static javax.swing.JCheckBox useLowerAlphabet;
    public static javax.swing.JCheckBox useSpecialChars;
    // End of variables declaration                   


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }
}
```

**PasswordGenerator.java**   **edited**

(Based on [this other post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/66993))

```
package passwordgenerator;

import java.security.SecureRandom;

public class PasswordGenerator {
    String charactersToBeUsed;

    private static final String UPPERCASE_CHARACTERS = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    private static final int DEFAULT_PASSWORD_LENGTH = 8;

    // default constructor
    public PasswordGenerator() { 
        this(UPPERCASE_CHARACTERS);
    }

    // constructor
    public PasswordGenerator(String characters) {
        this.charactersToBeUsed = characters;
    }

    public String generate() {
        return generate(DEFAULT_PASSWORD_LENGTH);
    }

    public String generate(int length) {
        char[] password = new char[length];

        char[] possibleCharacters = charactersToBeUsed.toCharArray();
        SecureRandom r = new SecureRandom();

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            password[i] = possibleCharacters[r.nextInt(possibleCharacters.length)];
        }
        return new String(password);
    }
}
```

**EnumAsciiCharacters.java**

```
package passwordgenerator;

public enum EnumAsciiCharacters {

    UPPERCASE( "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" ),
    LOWERCASE( "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" ),
    NUMERIC( "1234567890" ),
    SPECIAL( "~!@#$%^&*()_|" );

    private String characters;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return this.characters;
    }

    private EnumAsciiCharacters( String characters ) {
      this.characters = characters;
    }
} // EnumAsciiCharacters
```

Comment: There's a typo at `password[i] += ...` it should be `password[i] = ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) I'd extend the names of `UPPERCASE,` `LOWERCASE,` `NUMERIC,` `SPECIAL` with `_CHARACTERS.` That's clearer when using them later.

2) Since `defaultPasswordLength` is a `final` I'd name it `DEFAULT_PASSWORD_LENGTH.`

3) `characterString` isn't a good name. It's obvious to any decent Java programmer that this is a `String` and a string contains characters. I'd name it `charactersToBeUsed.`

4) I'd not refer to `GUI` inside `PasswordGenerator`. Thus it cannot be used without a GUI - in a command line tool, for instance. And it can't even be used without a GUI of a special kind: the one you provide.

I'd use [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) (DI) instead. That means supplying the `PasswordGenerator` with the characters to be used from outside. That's much more flexible for possible future users (=developers) of your class. So, inject `(String charactersToBeUsed)` via a constructor or via the `generate()` methods. Define a default in case this argument isn't given.

Think of [Separation of Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) (SoC): It's not up to the password generator to decide (via `finals)` which (limited) characters can or should be used. It's being told to it from its user.

Take a radio as an example: It's not up to the radio to decide which (limited) set of channels it can play. *You* tell it which channels you want to listen to and it plays them then.

5) Instead of `length*length*length*length*length`I'd use `java.Math.pow(length, 5).`

6) I'd use an array instead of (relatively slow) String concatenation at the generation (and rename `characters` to `possibleCharacters`):

```
char[] password = new char[length];
...
char[] possibleCharacters = charactersToBeUsed.toCharArray();
...
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  password[i] = possibleCharacters[r.nextInt(possibleCharacters.length)];
}
return new String(password);
```

7) Make `charactersToBeUsed` `private.`

8) For the convenience of users of your PG you could supply an `enum` (with a constructor) containing your default characters:

```
package passwordgenerator;

public enum AsciiCharacters
  {
  UPPERCASE( "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" ),
  LOWERCASE( "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" ),
  NUMERIC( "1234567890" ),
  SPECIAL( "~!@#$%^&*()_|" );

  private String characters;

  public String toString()
    {
    return this.characters;
    }

  private AsciiCharacters( String characters )
    {
    this.characters = characters;
    }
  } // AsciiCharacters
```

Thus the users have the choice to:

- use the predefined characters in any combination of them
- supply their own characters

Example:

```
String useThisCharacters = 
  String.format( "%s%s", AsciiCharacters.UPPERCASE, AsciiCharacters.LOWERCASE );
new PasswordGenerator( useThisCharacters );
```

Comment: I used your tips, from 1) to 6), thank you for your time.
Do i correctly outsourced chars from PasswordGenerator? I mean, it's working, of course, but I doubt that UPPERCASE_CHARACTERS in PasswordGenerator.java can stay. Should I make PasswordGenerator.java more independent? 
I also have doubt about Dependency Injection - it is correct way to have default chars in PG.java?
I cuted out file PasswordGenerator.java from project, added main function and launched it from command line - it is working correctly.

Comment: @nanomader You're welcome. That's why we are here. :-) Looks good and great that you made it work. `UPPERCASE_CHARACTERS` in `PG` is fine since this is the default. I'd call `this(UPPERCASE_CHARACTERS);` (_constructor chaining_) in the default constructor.

Comment: Be careful with `Math.pow()` for it is very slow and inefficient for smaller powers. Here it does not matter, but in some loop difference between `a*a*a*a` and `Math.pow(a,4)` can be quite significant. Or at least it was this way last time I checked, not sure whether compiler approach changed in java 8.

Answer (score 4):

> Should i use try catch in, for example, button handling or password generating?

try-catch is for handling exceptions. For example in the middle of downloading a URL the network connection can get disrupted and trigger an exception, which can be handled gracefully by retrying to download.
In your app, I don't see what can go wrong,
I don't see what kind of exceptions might be triggered.

"Should I use try catch" is a very strange question to ask.
Using try catch is typically not an option, but mandatory when it's needed.
It's not something you ask yourself.

> I saw some user answers who discouraged using try catch statement. I am reading a lot, and I see that everyone has own opinion.

I suspect there is a bigger context there when somebody discourages using try-catch.
It doesn't make sense to say so, the statement has no meaning,
without explaining the context where it would be true.
Using try-catch is not a matter of opinion,
the operations you're doing either force you to handle exceptions or don't,
not your choice.

> If i write another program, all by myself or in bigger part myself, can i post code here, even if we have here a lot of similar projects? Like my passwordGenerator - there are a lot of similar threads.

It's normal to have similar threads.
Code you wrote yourself, to the best of your knowledge,
fully working,
and you would like it peer-reviewed,
then this is a good place to post it.

#### Code review

The way you create the layout,
with the deeply chained `.addGroup`, add-this, add-that,
is a bit hard to read,
but I don't know how to do that better.
Maybe somebody else can advise you on that.

In the GUI class,
many variables that are declared members should be local variables instead:

> ```
> private javax.swing.JButton btnGenerate;
> private javax.swing.ButtonGroup buttonGroup1;
> private javax.swing.ButtonGroup buttonGroup2;
> private javax.swing.ButtonGroup buttonGroup3;
> private javax.swing.ButtonGroup buttonGroup4;
> private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
> private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
> private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
> private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
> private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
> private static javax.swing.JSlider jSlider1;
> ```

It's good to limit the scope of variables to the minimum.
The reason is simple:
when a variable is not accessible in a bigger scope than necessary,
it cannot be misused.

There is `jLabel3` which is used by more than one method,
so that cannot be converted to a local variable.
However, if it's so different from the others,
then it deserves a better name than "jLabel3",
as it's clearly a bit special.

And why do you refer to classes with the complete package names instead of importing them? This is very tedious.

Judging by `loadGUI`,
it looks like you're using Java 8.
In which case you can simplify some anonymous classes,
for example instead of:

> ```
>     btnGenerate.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
>         public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
>             btnGenerateActionPerformed(evt);
>         }
>     });
> ```

You can write:

```
    btnGenerate.addActionListener(this::btnGenerateActionPerformed);
```

There are some other places where you could apply the sample logic, for example:

```
    jButton2.addActionListener(GUI.this::copyToClipboard);
```

Comment: Just so you know, it looks like OP used net beans to generate his GUI, so that explains the fully qualified names and variables at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know. I'll go easy on posts like that in the future ;-)